# Most efficient way to convert ASCII to Binary in x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, binary, x86, ascii

I have a number stored in memory as ASCII and want to convert it to its binary value (multiplied by 100).

so 1.23 may be stored in memory in ASCII as 0x312E3233 and this should be converted to the binary value 123.

I currently have the following but is there a more efficient way?

```
mov eax,[esi]
xor eax, 0x302E3030
mov edx, eax
and edx, 0x000000FF
shr eax,8
jz skip
mov ecx,eax
and ecx, 0x000000FF
imul ecx, 10
add edx, ecx
shr eax,8
jz skip
shr eax,8
imul eax,100
add edx, eax
skip:
```

The ascii source is referenced by esi.

At the point of the label "skip", edx has the binary value.

Comment: If SSE2 is an option I suppose you could try multiplying all the digits in parallel, and then use a couple of horizontal adds to sum everything up. I don't know whether or not that'd be more efficient though. You could try it and do some measurements.

Comment: `more efficient` in terms of execution time, code size, elegance? (only one choice allowed ;)

Comment: More efficient = least execution time.

Comment: It gives right result. You will notice the shr eax,8 twice at the bottom to take care of the extra digit.

Comment: The code is tested and provides the right results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to not include those conditional jumps if the routine can work with zero values. BSWAP should be faster than 2 times shifting by 8. IMUL could be changed into LEA/ADD combo.

```
mov eax,[esi]
mov edx,eax
and edx,0x0000000F
mov ecx,eax
shr ecx,8
and ecx,0x0000000F
;;;imul ecx,10
lea ecx,[ecx+ecx*4]
add ecx,ecx
add edx,ecx
bswap eax
and eax,0x0000000F
;;;imul eax,100
lea eax,[eax+eax*4]
add eax,eax
lea eax,[eax+eax*4]
add eax,eax
add edx,eax
skip:
```

EDIT

The original question never stated that the input range would be [0.00,1.00]. 
In fact the example given (*1.23*) lies outside this range and so I understood the full range was implied. That's the main reason that I no longer included those conditional jumps.

Testing everyone's codes on a Pentium 133 in real address mode revealed these execution times.

```
              sudhanshu bahuguna    Rudy Velthuis         user3144770
[0.00,9.99]   19.640 sec            18.921 sec            19.161 sec  
[0.00,1.00]   13.244 sec            11.460 sec            19.161 sec
```

After several tests I found that replacing `imul ecx,10` with the well-known LEA/ADD combo was very profitable. Replacing `imul eax,100` on the other hand made things worse (by approximately the same amount). I realised that given a limited input range the last `jz skip` is crucial. So I introduced all these findings in both answers and got these execution times.

```
              sudhanshu bahuguna    Rudy Velthuis (2)     user3144770 (2)
[0.00,9.99]   19.640 sec            17.843 sec            17.364 sec  
[0.00,1.00]   13.244 sec            11.448 sec            12.035 sec
```

Still not overwhelmed by these results I conjured up a much faster solution that always executes in 9.580 sec.

```
movzx   eax, byte [esi+3]
add     eax,eax
lea     eax,[eax+eax*4-480]
add     al,[esi+1]
add     eax,eax
lea     eax,[eax+eax*4-480]
movzx   edx, byte [esi]
lea     edx,[eax+edx-48]
```

Comment: I benchmarked this solution as well as the other suggestion by @Rudy Velthuis. Tried it over 80 million conversions. My original code as well as all other suggestions run to within 2% of each other. And for multiple runs the winners changed. So I guess all solutions are largely similar. I think Core i5 on which I tested do manage to do the IMUL very fast. The IMUL vs LEA hack probably works on older x86 processors. Thanks everyone for the suggestions anyways.

Comment: I think theoretically the solution by @user3144770 should run faster. However since the input is 0.00 to 1.00 and relative random, the value 1.00 appears more or less once in 101 times. Since the above solution processes the digit before the decimal unconditionally it loses out on the average.

Answer (score 0):

A few simple things could improve this a little. Get rid of the comparatively slow `imul` and use `lea` and `add`:

```
    mov eax,[esi]
    xor eax,0x302E3030
    mov edx,eax
    jz skip
    and edx,0x000000FF
    shr eax,8
    jz skip
    mov ecx,eax
    and ecx,0x000000FF
    lea ecx,[ecx+4*ecx]
    add ecx,ecx
    add edx,ecx
    shr eax,8
    jz skip
    shr eax,8
    lea eax,[eax+4*eax]
    lea eax,[eax+4*eax]
    add eax,eax
    add eax,eax 
    add edx,eax
skip:
```

On modern processors, it probably doesn't make a huge difference, but it should still be noticeable.

Comment: The first *jz skip* will not deliver EDX as stated by the OP. (**At the point of the label "skip", edx has the binary value**)

Comment: Darn! You're right. Skip that line. <g> I just moved it, and now it should work correctly.

Comment: I didn't look into it, but somehow ISTM that the first multiplication by 10 could be used to multiply eax instead of ecx, so the second multiplication is only by 10 again.